# Does Juggernaut work on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, juggernaut

I'm building a Rails app that includes live group chat. I've heard Juggernaut is the best option for this. Does it work on Heroku?

Comment: juggernaut is INVINCIBLE! (sorry just had to say that XD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They did have experimental node.js support but it seems to be in closed beta for the timebeing. Expect a release soon.

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/9/20/an_update_on_heroku_node_js_support/

I have minimal sysadmin skills but managed to set up an Ubuntu 10.04 environment with relative ease. http://purebreeze.com/2011/03/adding-realtime-push-updates-to-agileista-using-juggernaut/

The 'easiest' option is probably to use [Pusher](http://pusherapp.com/) but probably not as fun or cost effective.

**UPDATED**

Heroku now fully support node.js

Here's a gist from the juggernaut author showing how he set up juggernaut on Heroku:

https://gist.github.com/1003748

I will also update my blog post shortly to reflect getting up and running.

It's much easier now!

Comment: Hmm...I'm wondering if this is outdated now that Heroku officially supports Node.JS. I'm wondering how Juggernaut works since Heroku does not currently support websockets. Does it fall back to long polling?