# Rails app and chat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chat

I'm developing this **[application](http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo)** and I want to add chat for users.

I don't want to go with the ajax polling stuff.

Is there any other way to integrate chatting (any good gem or any suggestion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Web sockets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)  Maybe. [For some browsers.](http://caniuse.com/websockets)

Comment: Agree, but it's an option.  Added a link to caniuse. I'm not sure that there's another viable option besides ajax poll or websocket.  You can always implement a capability-sniffing strategy -- use websockets if available otherwise revert to ajax poll.

Comment: Unless you want to do flash or java applet. But you don't want that.

Comment: I surely don't want to do that. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Your might want to check out [Pusher](http://www.pusher.com), and they have an [example chat app](http://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime_chat_widget) and here is their [device compatibility](http://pusher.com/docs/device_compatibility). They also have a [gem](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem), they use web sockets (like @PaulProgrammer's suggestion) but fallback to flash for older browsers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Looks like people in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810945/best-chat-gem-compatible-with-heroku) like [Mad Chatter](https://github.com/andrewhavens/mad_chatter).

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye) gem

here is [railsCaste](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) for it